# GWT FormPanel not submitting in IE - works fine on FF, Chrome, Safari

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, cross-browser, form-submit

I am using a simple FormPanel in GWT (com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FormPanel).

Once setting the  action for the form, in Firefox, Safari, Chrome the submit method works fine while in IE (8) nothing happens when submit is called (I am submitting a form to paypal, not that it matters).

I am on GWT 2.0. Is this some kind of known problem? Been looking around but couldn't find anything on the subject.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: it is surprising to see how many peculiar circumstances can cause IE to fail posting forms :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that the button you are using to submit the form is added to the Panel as well as the hidden fields. I got caught by it once, working on some browsers, not working in IE!

Comment: sounds peculiar behavior - I'll check that and get back to you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem some time ago. I solved it by changing the orders of the elements that belong to the `FormPanel` (can't remember exactly what was the order).

Try one of these:

- **Panel first**: Add the `FormPanel` to the main document (either through `RootPanel` or any other container that is already attached to the document) and then add the `FormPanel`'s elements
- **Panel elements first**: Add all the form elements to the `FormPanel`, then attach the FormPanel to the main document

Answer (score 0):

Are you using hidden fields?

If so try putting them into a separate HorizontalPanel which is than added the the form panel.

Have you tried sniffing the traffic, maybe the form is submitted and it is some other kind of problem?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion  - I am already adding a bunch of hidden input fields to a vertical panel then adding the panel to the form. Works fine in some browsers so it looks like the action is not getting executed on submit. Did not try sniffing - might give it a shot if I can't find easier way around.